# Unable to Compile maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins

I am using a maven project (v3.1.1) which I use for selenium automation. I have already hosted my project in Jenkins(in localhost) and trying to compile the project from the Jenkins itself.

```
com.eh.base
com.eh.pageobjects
com.eh.tests
```

[I am not using the structure like **src\main\resource**]

The maven plugin in Jenkins will achieve the compile process. I tried using maven plugin 2.2.1 as well as 3.1.1 with **compile** goal, it didn't work. In order to replicate this within the eclipse level. I tried to compile the maven project from the command prompt  using the commands **mvn clean**, **mvn compile**.

**BUILD RESULTS**:

```
D:\Shaw\Shaw\Projects\Branch\MyProject>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...


[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Shaw\Shaw\Projects\Branch\MyProject\src\main\resources
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.352s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 13 01:36:23 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From this, I hoping that it will compile and generate the class files in the **/target/classes**. But this has not done so. Since I am using the custom package for my project, I think I should try maven archetype. Please advice.

Please let me know if I missed anything.

**POM file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.eh</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyProject</name>

    <description>A sample Maven project that demonstrates how to integrate Sauce OnDemand with WebDriver tests that run using JUnit
    </description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-xml</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-xml.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>BaseLibrary</groupId>
            <artifactId>BaseLibrary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/BaseLibrary.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-examples</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-examples.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-greplog</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-greplog.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-jdbc.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-nblr</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-nblr.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-nbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-nbp.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-swing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-swing.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-wadl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-wadl.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-xmldog</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-xmldog.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>TestNGFileGenerator</groupId>
            <artifactId>TestNGFileGenerator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/TestNGFileGenerator.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibs-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibs-core.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SauceREST</groupId>
            <artifactId>SauceREST</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/SauceREST.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        :
                        <property>
                            <name>org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showSuccess>false</showSuccess>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                    <zip destfile="${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports/reports.zip"
                         basedir="${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports/"
                         includes="**/*.html,**/*.xml,**/*.css"
                    />
                    </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
             </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sauce-eh</id>
            <name>sauce_quickstart</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java-net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>saucelabs-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Show your pom file? Where did you located your source files which you like to compile? `src/main/java` or in case of tests i would assume `src/test/java`.

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I have added my pom.xml in the original post. My source files are /src/com/eh/tests,  /src/com/eh/base, /src/com/eh/pageobjects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to follow the [default folder layout of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). That will make your life easier.

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── java
│   └── resources
└── test
    ├── java
    └── resources
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to tinker with the default folder structure of Maven projects.  It seems that you have got rid of `main/src` and `test` altogether.  I am not sure how, where or whether you are storing your test classes.  Not having tests for your code can be costly in the long run.

Anyway, if you do decide to stick with your non-standard project structure, you will have to set the path to the source code as follows:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

This will inform Maven that your source code is under `src` instead of `src/main/java`.  If you also have resource files, such as XML or properties files, you will have to pass their locations to Maven as well using `build/resources` tag.